# Lenovo Edge laptop with Windows 8 has white, flashing dots on the touch screen

Tags: windows-8, lenovo-laptop, touchscreen

after spraying my touch screen lightly with a screen cleaner [duh] and wiping it with a microfiber cloth, I have several flashing dots on my screen. Rebooting hasn't helped.  The touch screen is unresponsive and I am unable to calibrate it.  I have checked for driver updates and I have uninstalled and reinstalled the driver. The only way I can use the PC is my disabling the touch screen using device manager.

Also when I reboot the PC, the settings screen comes up rather than the Windows 8, tiled screen.

Answer (score 0):

The flashing dots are the touch cursors. Somehow the screen cleaner has shorted out the tiny wires in your touch screen which is now sending false touch info to the OS. What probably happened is the screen cleaner seeped between poorly sealed layers in the digitizer allowing the cleaning solution to short out the connections.

I believe the remedy to this will be to replace the digitizer.

You may have luck contacting the manufacturer if it is still under warranty.

If you provide model/submodel info for the laptop I can be more specific